# $(this).addClass не работает

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

В таблице есть такая строка:

```
<tr class="homeInfo" onclick="AreaToggle()" >
```

Скрипт такой:

```
function AreaToggle() {
    $(this).addClass("hidden");
}
```

А в итоге класс не добавляется. toggleClass тоже не работает.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: напишите так : `onclick="AreaToggle(this)"` и в функции используйте не `this` а параметр

Comment: Rostyslav Kuzmovych, спасибо, заработало

Comment: Вам там развернутый ответ с обьяснениями дали, тыкните на галку )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При таком объявлении `this` внутри функции указывает на глобальный объект (window) либо `undefined` если указана директива `"use strict"`.

Поэтому `$(this).addClass` не сработал.

Для исправления нужно либо передать элемент непосредственно в функцию:

```js
function AreaToggle(el) {
  $(el).addClass("hidden");
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="homeInfo" onclick="AreaToggle(this)">Click</span>
```

Либо добавлять обработчик с помощью `jQuery` либо `addEventListner`, а не непосредственно в разметке.

Comment: а если так : `onclick="AreaToggle.apply(this)"` ?)

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych, можно и так